# update Australian passport from UK

Tags: uk, passports, australia, australian-citizens, embassies

I have legally changed my name.
I am trying to update my Australian Passport.
I live in the UK under a Tier 2 Visa.

I have assembled my documents and have everything I need.
But because my current passport has a different name than my new one should, I can't do a renewal by post.
I apparently need to go into the High Commission in person.

However, their appointment booking website says "Fully booked" for next 6 months then, for November it says something like  "No appointments available".

Am I correct in saying that more appointments (for November) will come out on 1st of July?

Are there any other options for updating my passport?
I will be back in Australia for 2 weeks in October.

Comment: Because your name has changed, the Australian government classes this as an _application for a passport_ rather than a _renewal_. I don't know the answer to your main question about appointments in the UK, but you can use the [urgent application service](https://www.passports.gov.au/urgent-applications) when you're back in Australia.